# Retrieving a Subset of Fields from Mongodb in Java

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm trying to retrieve only a subset of fields from mongodb using Java driver. In documentation I found a way to do this javascript-way

```
db.posts.find( { tags : 'tennis' }, { comments : 0 } );
```

Trouble is, if I do similar thing in java

```
db.getCollection("posts").find(new BasicDBObject("comments",0));
```

What it does, is filtering objects where `"comments" == 0`, and does pull `comments` field as usual.

How to do this properly in java?

Comment: why a +1 for such a basic rtfm question?

Comment: Are you sure it's in manual? It is described, but for javascript, not for java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to use it the following way:

```
BasicDBObject keys = new BasicDBObject();
keys.put("comments", 0);
db.getCollection("posts").find(new BasicDBObject(), keys);
```