# Retrieve _ids from mongo database

Tags: java, mongodb, database

I'm trying to get a list of mongo "_ids" from a database using Java. I don't need any other part of the objects in the database, just the "_id".

This is what I'm doing right now:

```
// Another method queries for all objects of a certain type within the database.
Collection<MyObject> thingies = this.getMyObjects();

Collection<String> ids = new LinkedList<String>();
for (MyObject thingy : thingies) {
  ids.add(thingy.getGuid());
}
```

This seems horribly inefficient though... is there a way just to query mongo for objects of a certain type and return only their "_ids" without having to reassemble the entire object and extract it?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieving a Subset of Fields from Mongodb in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714939/retrieving-a-subset-of-fields-from-mongodb-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

The [find()](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.11.2/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#find%28com.mongodb.DBObject,%20com.mongodb.DBObject%29) method has an overload where you can pass the keys that you want to retrieve back from the query or those that you don't want.

So you could try this:

```
BasicDBObject qyery = new BasicDBObject("someKey","someValue");
BasicDBObject keys = new BasicDBObject("_id", 1);
DBCursor cursor = collection.find(query, keys);
```